# get_target_property() called with non-existent target "opencv_world"

Tags: opencv, cmake, cmakelists-options

I'm pretty new to using CMake to build/compile OpenCV projects in Visual Studio Code.

From my understanding so far, this is the 'typical' CMake file 'format' if I want to compile a OpenCV project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(OpenCV_Hello_World VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Find OpenCV package
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Include OpenCV headers
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Create the executable
add_executable(OpenCV_Hello_World main.cpp)

# Link OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Hello_World PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

In my main directory, I have :

- `main.cpp`
- `CMakelists.txt`
- `build` folder to hold all the files that get generated from the CMake file

With the CMake file listed above, when I use `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` and `make` to build/compile my `main.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at E:/Coding Folder/OpenCV Folder/build/win-install/x64/vc16/lib/OpenCVConfig.cmake:290 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "opencv_world".
```

But if I were to specify where my `OpenCV lib` files are at with the `set()` command, I'm able to compile/build everything just fine.

Here's the CMake file that I'm currently using

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(OpenCV_Hello_World VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Set the OpenCV directory
#set(OpenCV_DIR " INSERT PATH TO OPENCV LIB HERE ")

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Find OpenCV package
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Include OpenCV headers
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Create the executable
add_executable(OpenCV_Hello_World main.cpp)

# Link OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Hello_World PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I was under the heavy impression that the `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` command would 'find' my OpenCV files and I'm confused on why that's not the case.

Comment: File `<...>/win-install/x64/vc16/lib/OpenCVConfig.cmake` describes installation of OpenCV for **Visual Studio**. It is not compatible with `Unix Makefiles` generator, which configures the project for **Linux** (you run the configure under WSL, don't you?).

Comment: To be fully transparent with you, the only reason I use `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` and the `make` command is purely so I don't have to `cd` into the `Release` folder if I used `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` and `cmake --build . --config Release` to build and compile with my Visual Studio configuration.

But to answer your question if I'm "Running the configure under WSL" I'm using a `Powershell` terminal in Visual Studio Code

Comment: What **compiler** do you use when configure the project? Normally, CMake prints the compiler at the beginning of the configuration output.